# TCP connection, serversocket.accept when running it wont create the socket

Tags: java

This is my code when I run it in debug mode in eclipse it shows me that it doesn´t continue it stops a stays in the code where I have put an arrow.

```
    private ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    private Socket socket= null;
    private ObjectInputStream inputStream= null;    
public void ConnectTCP(){
        try{
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5000);
       ---->socket = serverSocket.accept();
            inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            System.out.print("Server is Running");
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your socket is already created at this line. Because server binds to a port, at the moment ServerSocket constructor is called. As for accept method, [due to JavaDoc](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept()) it

> Listens for a connection to be made to this socket and accepts it. The method blocks until a connection is made.
>   A new Socket s is created and, if there is a security manager, the security manager's checkAccept method is called with s.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() and s.getPort() as its arguments to ensure the operation is allowed. This could result in a SecurityException.

So, accept method is just waiting for client connections, that is the reason, why execution stops at this point. May be, it could be helpfull to read a [java official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html) for writing a server side.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it won't stop, it waiting for connection.
When a client want to connect it then it connect with that socket and program flow goes next line.